# How can I write a program to multiply strings?

Tags: c++

I have to code a program for a scenario that get like,

1. character and a number between <>
2. word and a number between []
3. sentence and a number between ()

   Finally have to print those that many number of times.
   Examples:

Sample: 1

```
 Input: A<4>
 Output: A A A A
```

Sample: 2

```
 Input: good[3]
 Output: good good good
```

Sample: 3

```
 Input: A is good. (2)
 Output: A is good. A is good.
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
char a[1000];
cout<< "Enter a char, word or sentece:" << endl;
gets(a);
int i;
for(i=0;a[i];i++);
int n=i, k , l=0, m=0;
while(1){
    for(k=l;a[k]!='<'&&a[k]!='('&&a[k]!='[';k++);
    m=k;
    int o=int (a[m+1])-48;
    int u=0;
    for(i=1;i<=o;i++)
    for(u=l;u<m;u++)
    {
    cout<<a[u];
    }
    if(m+2==n-1)
    return 0;
    l=m+3;
}
}
```

It works but just for 1-9 numbers.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not use `std::string` and `find_first_of`?  That would cut down the code by more than half.

Comment: I am new to c++ and I do not know how to use find_first of. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: You're writing basically `C` code with very little to no C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I found two major mistakes in your code.

**Mistake # 01:**

> It is working for only 0-9 numbers.

**Reason:**

You are checking just one number after `<`, `(` or `[`, in fact you need to iterate over the digits of the number. Then find the exact number by multiplying previous number by 10 and adding the next digit.

**Mistake # 02:**

> It is not terminating and the `while` loop is an infinite loop.

**Reason:**

Your `if` condition for `return` is wrong, it works only if your digit is a `one-digit number`. So you also need to update the terminating condition as well. You can cater this when you are checking the size of `digit` in a loop.

I have made a little change in your code and now it works fine.

**Updated Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[1000];
    cout << "Enter a char, word or sentece:" << endl;
    gets(a);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; a[i]; i++);
    int n = i, k, l = 0, m = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        for (k = l; a[k] != '<'&&a[k] != '('&&a[k] != '['; k++);
        m = k;
        int o = int(a[m + 1]) - '0';
        int terminate = 2;
        for (int j = m + 2; a[j] != '>'&&a[j] != ')'&&a[j] != ']'; j++)
        {
            o = o * 10 + (a[j]) - '0';
            terminate++;
        }
        int u = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= o; i++)
        for (u = l; u<m; u++)
        {
            cout << a[u];
        }
        if (m + terminate == n - 1)
            return 0;
        l = m + 3;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> It works but just for 1-9 numbers.

You are extracting a digit in line

```
int o=int (a[m+1])-48;
```

and are using is it as the final number.

You need to store the number and keep adding to it if you find more digits.

1. Declare `o` before the loop and initialize it `0`.
2. Keep adding to it in the loop.
3. Move the printing loop out of the outer loop.

```
// Initialize o
int o = 0;

while(1){
    for(k=l; a[k]!='<' && a[k]!='(' && a[k]!='['; k++);
    m=k;

    // Add to o
    for(++k; a[k]!='>' && a[k]!=')' && a[k]!=']'; k++)
    {
       o = 10*o + a[k]-'0';
    }

    if(m+2==n-1)
    return 0;
    l=m+3;
}

// Print
for(i=1;i<=o;i++)
for(int u=l;u<m;u++)
{
   cout<<a[u];
}
```

**Disclaimer:** The code is untested.

Comment: It doesnt work . for 1-9 numbers doest print anything , and for bigger numbers program will crash.

Comment: @Mr.Taj, add `cout` statements at key locations to print the important variables and see where the logic error is. It's not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this the "C++ way", usage of `std::string`,   [std::string::find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), and [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is all you really need.

First, we know what symbols to look for that start and terminate the number sequence:

```
const char* symbolStart = "(<[";
const char* symbolEnd = ")>]";

std::string test = "A<4>";  // for example
```

The next thing is to discover the number:

```
size_t startPos, endPos;
startPos = test.find_first_of(symbolStart);
```

The `startPos` will point to the first character that matches any in the `symbolStart`.  Next we find the position of the termination character:

```
endPos = test.find_first_of(symbolEnd, startPos);
```

Given we now have `startPos` and `endPos`, we know where the number is.  All that we need to do is to get this string and convert it to an integer:

```
std::string num = test.substr(startPos+1, endPos - startPos - 1);
value = atoi(num.c_str());
```

We now have the number, and all we need to do now is to write the string that appears before `startPos` a repeated number of times:

```
    text = test.substr(0, startPos);
    for (int i = 0; i < value; ++i)
        std::cout << text << " ";
```

So putting this all together (a function `repeater` was created to test this):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void repeater(const std::string& test)
{
    const char* symbolStart = "(<[";
    const char* symbolEnd = ")>]";

    // get start and end of number 
    size_t startPos = test.find_first_of(symbolStart);
    size_t endPos = test.find_first_of(symbolEnd, startPos + 1);

    // extract the number 
    string num = test.substr(startPos + 1, endPos - startPos - 1);

    // get the value
    int value = atoi(num.c_str());
    string text = test.substr(0, startPos);

    // output repeated text
    for (int i = 0; i < value; ++i)
        cout << text << " ";
    cout  << "\n";        
}

int main()
{
    repeater("A<50>");
    repeater("good[3]") ;
    repeater("A is good. (2)");
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/ZRZ8xp)

Note that we're assuming the input is valid.  There is no error checking in the sample code.